# Setting Environment Variables for Android Studio

Tags: 14.04, android, environment-variables, android-studio

I am running cordova, so i wanted to install android-sdk. Here is the path

```
Android-Studio Path = /home/apps/android-studio
Android- /Android/Sdk
```

Whenever i tried to add via export.. it seems to be included. But i got the error always

```
ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

How can i add the environment variables manually.

In the `/etc/environment`, i tried to add the environment variables manually.

But i got the same got the same error.

Here is what i have in the `/opt/environment` so far

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

What should i add next to make the command work `cordova run android`

Comment: Hi did you figure this out @SA_ , I want to do the xact same thing

Answer (score 6):

In the console just type these (remember to change to your current location)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
```

If you want to make it permanent just add those lines in the `~/.bashrc` file.